# Golang: ":GoRun" in vim-go and "go install" have conflicting GOPATH requirements on Windows

Tags: vim, go, windows-7, vim-plugin

I am running:

- Windows 7
- [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/hosting/moved?project=conemu-maximus5) combined with [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) as my command prompt
- `go version go1.5.1 windows/amd64`
- [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/) v1.2 as my editor

When I use the following GOPATH:

`$GOPATH=C:\Users\marc\Desktop\coding\go`

And I try to run a Go program directly from `VIM-go` using the command

`:GoRun`

I receive the following error:

`go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "C".`

When I change my go path to:

`$GOPATH = /Users/marc/Desktop/coding/go`

The `:GoRun` command is working fine, but then `go install` throws the following error:

`go install: no install location for directory C:\Users\marc\Desktop\coding\go\src\github.com\marc\test outside GOPATH`
`For more details see: go help gopath`

So what value should `$GOPATH` have such that both commands are working?

**--- I FOUND THE ANSWER ---**

I thought I post my solution for people with the same problem. Change GOPATH to:

`$GOPATH = /C/Users/marc/Desktop/coding/go`